# How Do You Reset Font Size

Tags: firemonkey

When I change the font size to any value I have not been able set it back to (Default).

Is it possible or do you have to delete the component and start over?

Comment: why delete the component when you can revert to a "default" class which contains the "original" font settings ?

Comment: I guess I did not make myself clear in my question.  How do you revert back to the "default" class.  You cannot type (Default) because it will give you an error.

Comment: it depends on what "you" mean by default. there are default browsers styles which are different on each browser. are you talking about that?

Comment: Okay, last try.  I am talking about RAD Studio, Delphi, Firemonkey, XE7.  This has nothing to with browsers. When you set the font size to a number how do you set it back to default.

Comment: you're right, my bad

Comment: Never mind.  Apparently you have to try every number in the world until you ACCIDENTALLY hit the right one that changes to say "(Default)".  Oh well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each FireMonkey controls, which has published **TextSettings** property also has **DefaultTextSettings** (public). So you can get default value for all text settings by

```
Label1.DefaultTextSettings;
```

for example with **TLabel**.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Go to property "StyledSettings" and set "Size" with "True"